# Сохранить бинарное дерево из базы в массив

Tags: php, бинарное-дерево

Имею такую таблицу:

```
id, id_user, left_user, right_user

id - просто ID в таблице
id_user - ID пользователя
left_user - человек под id_user слева
right_user - человек по id_user справа
```

Как это перенести из базы данных в массив PHP, чтобы разбить по уровням? Я пробовал сделать так:

```
public function createTree($id_user) {
        $data = [];
        $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('id_user' => $id_user));

        if ($user !== null) {
            $data[] = $this->createTree($user->left_user);
            $data[] = $this->createTree($user->right_user);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Но массив возвращается с одним элементом, и не получается разбивать по уровням. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: При вызове функции Вы передаете ID пользователя, который является корнем дерева, или первого попавшегося из базы?

Comment: ID пользователя является корнем дерева

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу из кода переменная *$data* существует только в функции *createTree* поэтому вы получаете только результат последнего добавления. Переменная должна быть свойством класса *$this->data* или быть объявленной [глобальной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) *global $data*.